# How to aggregate percentile_disc() function over date time

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, aggregate-functions, percentile

I have tables like the following:

```
recorddate score 
2021-05-01   0
2021-05-01   1 
2021-05-01   2
2021-05-02   3
2021-05-02   4
2021-05-03   5
2021-05-07   6
```

And want to get the 60th percentile for `score` per week. I tried:

```
select distinct 
       recorddate
     , PERCENTILE_disc(0.60) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY score)
                             OVER (PARTITION BY recorddate) AS top60
from tbl;
```

It returned something like this:

```
recorddate top60
2021-05-01  1
2021-05-02  4
2021-05-03  5
2021-05-07  6
```

But my desired result is like weekly aggregation (7 days).
For example for the week ending on 2021-05-07:

```
recorddate                    top60
2021-05-01 ~ 2021-05-07        2
```

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: What is "top60" supposed to be?  And why does your week span 8 days?

Comment: I edited my question about week.  top60 is cumulative ranking . so that I'd like to sort score in a week and get top60% score. thanks

Comment: Heisenberg . . . I still don't understand what a "cumulative ranking" is supposed to mean in this context.  Perhaps Erwin Brandstetter understands better.

Comment: @Gordon: More of an educated guess, really.

Comment: @Heisenberg: I took the liberty to edit and make it clearer. Did I get it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('week', recorddate) AS week
     , percentile_disc(0.60) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY score) AS top60
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1;
```

That's the discrete value at the 60th percentile for each week (where actual data exists) - where 60 % of the rows in the same group (in the week) are the same or smaller. To be precise, in the words of [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-ORDEREDSET-TABLE):

> the first value within the ordered set of aggregated argument values whose position in the ordering equals or exceeds the specified fraction.

Adding your format on top of it:

```sql
SELECT to_char(week_start, 'YYYY-MM-DD" ~ "')
    || to_char(week_start + interval '6 days', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS week
     , top60
FROM  (
   SELECT date_trunc('week', recorddate) AS week_start
        , percentile_disc(0.60) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY score) AS top60
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub;
```

I would rather call it something like "percentile_60".